# rails controller respond_to format with two extensions (e.g. tar.gz)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mime-types, respond-to

Is there a mechanism or accepted approach for responding to requests that have a more complicated format extension?

My specific scenario involves returning a `plist` file. However, I need to sometimes return this file as an `XML plist` file and sometimes as a binary `plist` file.

I thought that URLs composed like `/resources.xml.plist` and `/resources.binary.plist` would be a nice way to distinguish between them. I'd then need to add a MIME type for `binary.plist` and one for `xml.plist` and then somehow respond_to these formats.

Does any one know how this might be accomplished and/or have ideas for a nicer approach?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at tutorial "[Using custom mime types](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2006/12/19/using-custom-mime-types)".

```
Mime::Type.register "application/xml", :plist_xml, [], ["xml.plist"]
Mime::Type.register "application/octet-stream", :plist_binary, [], ["binary.plist"]

...

respond_to do |format|
  format.plist_xml { ... }
  format.plist_binary { ... }
end
```

Comment: Props for reminding me about the extension aliases, however this doesn't work as rails doesn't recognise the route. I'll play around with the `routes.rb` a bit to see if that gets it going.

Comment: Changing the routes to be something like this (at least, in Rails 3) did the trick: `resources :people, :constraints => { :format => /[a-z]+(\.[a-z]+)?/ }`